# How to configure Amazon S3 bucket so that external vendors can drop daily files in relevant folders within that bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the best way to configure Amazon S3 buckets so that 3rd party external vendor can CREATE folders and DROP files (xml, json, csv etc) in relevant folders within that S3 bucket?

I very much new to AWS world any suggestions or guidelines on that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of credentials do you want to give these vendors? Do you want to give them an IAM User (normally only used for internal staff, but can be used for trusted entities), or do they authenticate via a web application? (Do they authenticate at all?) How many vendors are there? Do the vendors have their own AWS account? Please tell us as much as possible!

Comment: How will you consume these? only from the AWS account the bucket exists in or will you want to share the objects with other AWS accounts? This makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

This question lacks some detail, but there are a few ways to make it happen:

- Create a group within AWS and assign a policy to the group that allows `s3:PutObject` only on the specific bucket. Create users for the vendors that are within those groups and give the vendors those credentials.
- Use the same logic above, except instead of creating users, use Amazon Cognito.
- (Depending on time): create a UI that allows users to sign in and upload. This sometimes isn't the best to hear but is also a really good way to write something that can be used in other larger applications.